# C# Save file with "/" in name

Tags: c#, file, filenames

FileName contains e.g. Legend/Dery//Times

```
File.WriteAllBytes("/Pictures" + FileName, buffer);
```

I can´t save the file because the "/" considered as path, I also can´t remove the "/", because I need it for further processing. Is there any way of saving such file?

Comment: Filenames can't contain slash characters. It is filesystem limitation.

Comment: instead of using "/" for further processing, can you use other char to further process? there is a discussion on the [illegal file name for different OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do? why can't you use another symbol? why do you need to throw a string with some split marker around?

Comment: i will replace the illegal characters. I didn't want to waste unnecessary computing power, But as I see it the only way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're out of luck. A forward slash can't be part of a file name.

You need to *escape* it somehow (i.e. change the name but provide a way of changing it back), but there isn't really a conventional way of doing that.

I've seen `%` been used for this purpose, with `%%` used to denote a single `%`, and something like `%f` for a forward slash, `%b` for a backslash, etc.

Comment: That is really too bad :/ Thanks for your prompt reply. i will replace the illegal characters. :) I didn't want to waste unnecessary computing power, But as I see it the only way

Answer (score 1):

There are [rules for names and folders defined by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247) that mean you are not allowed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of escaping in i suggest normalizing your input both when you save a file and when you try to access a file:

```cs
//replace all illegal characters with regex (with a dash):
new Regex(@"[<>:""/\\|?*]").Replace("Inpu|t","-")

//Or just replace all non alpha numeric characters (with a dash): 
new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]").Replace("Inpu|t","-")
```

this way you will always have clean file and folder names and don't have to worry about illegal names.